# Missing methods after upgrading to automapper 3

Tags: c#, automapper

I have just upgraded to Automapper 3 from version 2. There are two methods which I use in my projects:

`IsListOrDictionaryType()` and `ToNullSafeString()`

I am using .NET 4.0.

Does anyone have any suggestions/thoughts?

**UPDATE**
THere are four additional namespaces In Automapper 3.0.0. `Impl`, `Internal`, `Mappers`, `QueryableExtensions`. The 'missing' functions are in `Internal` but then so are other object methods and types so that does not appear to be a solution.

Comment: Which specific version of AutoMapper? 3.0 is the latest released, and 3.1 as the latest pre-release.

Comment: Sorry typo - I have upgraded to 3.0.0 from version 2.

Comment: @JimmyBogard I have tried various way to do this (see above) but am getting nowhere. Could it be a .NET 4.0 problem? Thanks. (Great product by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like they've moved to the AutoMapper.Internal namespace as per this issue: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/311

Comment: Hi Ryan, I tried as suggested - see update above. Am I missing something.

Answer (score 1):

All i needed to do was add

```
using AutoMapper.Internal;
```

at the top of my mapper profile .cs and it worked fine.

Comment: Hi Jamie. I tried that but that then caused a large number of other standard functions to fail - hence my response below.

Answer (score 0):

For those, like me, who are less well versed in some of the detail of the changes I used the following:

```
AutoMapper.Internal.PrimitiveExtensions.IsListOrDictionaryType(myData.GetType())
```

which returns a Boolean and

```
AutoMapper.Internal.PrimitiveExtensions.ToNullSafeString(myString)
```

which returns a string (sic).

Answer (score 0):

This is a side response, but if you're using ToNullSafeString and upgraded now to v4.0 the method is simply gone forever.

From https://github.com/paulbatum/automapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/Internal/PrimitiveExtensions.cs you can see the earlier implementation and do it yourself, to reduce dependency on this method.

You should do something similar to:

```
return value == null ? string.Empty : value.ToString();
```